# Ubuntu 16.04 compiling FFMPEG with libfaac

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, aac

I tried in different ways by reading various documents. I was not able to compile FFMPEG with the libfacc library but only with fdk_aac.

https://gist.github.com/teocci/f7a438013a0197a91446ee86de41faee

I need to integrate it with a plugin for an internet site.

Someone can tell me how to proceed.

Thank you

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the native encoder?

Answer (score 1):

FAAC support has been removed from FFmpeg since v3.2.

You either need to use an older version, or skip FAAC and simply use the built-in `aac` encoder. The `libfdk_aac` encoder also offers good quality, but it's an external dependency.

See http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC for more info.